# I couldn't display random images without duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i'm working on a task which will display random images. The code that i have shows random images but actually i want to display random images without duplicates. How to get this done. Help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
var images = ['https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg'];

var imagesused = [];
$('.advertisement div').each(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
  $(this).append('<img src="' + images[rand] + '"/>');
  if (imagesused.indexOf(images[rand]) != -1) images.splice(rand, 1);
  else imagesused.push(images[rand]);
});
```

```css
.advertisement div img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advertisement">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are only `4` images in `array`. So just display them all.

Comment: Actually here i try to change the place of the images on page refresh without duplicates.

Comment: @ Pkprabu see my answer its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of original array. And after adding the random image remove it from copy of array.You don't need to create `imagesUsed` as you removing it from the array.

```js
var images = ['https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg'];
//making copy of original array.
var tempImgs = images.slice(0)
$('.advertisement div').each(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tempImgs.length);
  $(this).append('<img src="' + tempImgs[rand] + '"/>');         
  tempImgs.splice(rand, 1);
});
```

```css
.advertisement div img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advertisement">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya its working. But it shows same place some times, if i refresh it.

Comment: @Pkprabu yes because there only `4` images which are very less. So there are some chances of same order as initial.If you will increase images it will work fine.

Comment: I want to show images along with links. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be like this, this way is can randomize them no matter how small or big your array is

first create a method which shuffle them

```
    function shuffle(a) {
        var j, x, i;
        for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            x = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = x;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

and then you use it before looping your array

```
images = shuffle(images);
```

```js
var images = ['https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/1.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/2.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/3.jpeg', 'https://cdn.paperindex.com/banner/advertisement/4.jpeg'];

function shuffle(a) {
 var j, x, i;
 for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
     j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
     x = a[i];
     a[i] = a[j];
     a[j] = x;
 }
 return a;
}

   images = shuffle(images);

var imagesused = [];
$('.advertisement div').each(function(x) {
  $(this).append('<img src="' + images[x] + '"/>');
});
```

```css
.advertisement div img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="advertisement">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```